# Change textual content of an element node with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<sce xmlns:type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<node>
  <type>LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE</type>
  <node_properties>
    <node_property>
      <name>MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</name>
      <label>Palette attribute colorization</label>
      <value>
        <type:anyType xsi:type="xs:string">pop</type:anyType>
      </value>
    </node_property>
  </node_properties>
 </node>
</sce>
```

With several nodes all having a lot of node_properties.

I'm trying to change the value `MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` to `COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME`.
For now, I have the following code that selects the property (some Nodes of other types can have the property `MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` and I don't want to change it for these other types)

```
<xsl:template match= "*[type='LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE']/node_properties/node_property[name='MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME']">
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried a lot of things, but for the life of me I can't change this damn value. I've seen a lot of questions here, but can't find the one that fits my requirements.

How do I change the value of an attribute once I found it ?

Update : I added the namespaces required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is not a well-formed XML document. No XSLT processor will accept it, because two namespace prefixes are not bound.

Caveat: Your title suggests you are trying to change an attribute value, but what you'd like to change:

```
<name>MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</name>
```

Is *not* an attribute. This is an element with text content. So, you should rather ask for a way to change the textual content of an element node.

**XML Input**

As you can see, I have modified the input to include *namespace declarations* for `xsi:` and `type:`.

```
<node xmlns:type="www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <type>LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE</type>
  <node_properties>
    <node_property>
      <name>MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</name>
      <label>Palette attribute colorization</label>
      <value>
        <type:anyType xsi:type="xs:string">pop</type:anyType>
      </value>
    </node_property>
  </node_properties>
 </node>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>   
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[type='LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE']/node_properties/node_property[name='MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME']/name/text()">
        <xsl:text>COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node xmlns:type="www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <type>LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE</type>
   <node_properties>
      <node_property>
         <name>COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</name>
         <label>Palette attribute colorization</label>
         <value>
            <type:anyType xsi:type="xs:string">pop</type:anyType>
         </value>
      </node_property>
   </node_properties>
</node>
```

---

**EDIT**: You have edited your question and extended the input sample. Thanks! The document is still not well-formed because the `sce` element is not closed properly.

The stylesheet above works with either inputs, given this new document as input, the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sce xmlns:type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <node>
      <type>LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE</type>
      <node_properties>
         <node_property>
            <name>COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</name>
            <label>Palette attribute colorization</label>
            <value>
               <type:anyType xsi:type="xs:string">pop</type:anyType>
            </value>
         </node_property>
      </node_properties>
   </node>
</sce>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for the semantic precision, it's the first time i put my hands on XSLT. I edited the title according to your precision.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match= "*[type='LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE']/node_properties/node_property/name[.='MODEL_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your **corrected** input, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sce xmlns:type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <node>
    <type>LAYER_FEATURE_EXTRUDED_NODE</type>
    <node_properties>
      <node_property>
        <name>COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME</name>
        <label>Palette attribute colorization</label>
        <value>
          <type:anyType xsi:type="xs:string">pop</type:anyType>
        </value>
      </node_property>
    </node_properties>
  </node>
</sce>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already applied Mathias answer though. I upvote you anyway.